# Kotlin Multiplatform error: directive doesn't match file location

Tags: android, android-studio, package, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to share code between Android and iOS with Kotlin Multiplatform. The sharing part works perfectly but I have some issues to import in a common file the androidApp package. I would like to use the res folder located in androidApp in the shared class.
This is my tree directory[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs1G7.png):

[DirectoryTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs1G7.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Usually you don’t have to import specific platform package to the shared part. The direction is quite the opposite. Use the shared part in the native ones. If you need to shared resources in an Android manner I suggest you to have a look here:  https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources

Comment: Thanks! That library is what I'm looking for. I want to share strings (localized) and resources.

Comment: Glad to know. So I’ll post my comment as the answer ;-]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you don’t have to import specific platform package to the shared part.

The direction is quite the opposite.

Use the shared part in the native ones.

If you need to share resources in an Android manner I suggest you to have a look here:

https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources